# Rotate rectangle around an axis in flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, rotation

I was trying to rotate a group(rectangle) on the bottom right coordinates using flex..

See the image [image: expected result]

how to achieve this rotation ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting originX and originY of the effect to the width and height of the component you're rotating?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to a tutorial that shows how to do it:

http://www.flashandmath.com/howtos/rotation/